# Update AzureAD/O365 UPN via Graph

Tags: powershell, azure, office365, microsoft-graph-api

I am attempting to update the UPN of an Azure AD user (loaded with Azure AD Connect) in a federated domain via MS Graph leveraging the .Net ADAL library in Powershell.  I am reasonably certain that I have everything configured correctly within Azure and in the PS, because if I issue a command to update the usageLocation attribute, it works (clipped for brevity):

```
$UPN="user@mytenant.edu"
$Body=@{UsageLocation="JP"} | ConvertTo-JSON
$Result=Invoke-RestMethod -Method PATCH -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${UPN}" -Headers @{Authorization=$authenticationResult.CreateAuthorizationHeader()} -ContentType "application/json" -Body $Body
$user=Invoke-RestMethod -Method GET -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${UPN}?`$select=usageLocation" -Headers @{Authorization=$authenticationResult.CreateAuthorizationHeader()} -ContentType "application/json"
$user.usageLocation

JP
```

But, if I attempt to update the UPN to a non-federated domain (so I do not run afoul of the issue described in http://blogs.perficient.com/microsoft/2013/03/changing-upn-for-office-365-account-between-two-sso-domains/), I get back an Internal Server Error (500):

```
$UPN="user@mytenant.edu"
$Body=@{userPrincipalName="user@tenant.onmicrosoft.com"} | ConvertTo-JSON
$Result=Invoke-RestMethod -Method PATCH -Uri "https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/${UPN}" -Headers @{Authorization=$authenticationResult.CreateAuthorizationHeader()} -ContentType "application/json" -Body $Body

Invoke-RestMethod : The remote server returned an error: (500) Internal Server Error.
```

I've tried many different variations, including retrieving the Azure AD GUID and using that rather than UPN in the PATCH command and using the older Azure AD Graph (which returns the same 500 error).  I can make the change using O365 Powershell commands:

```
Set-MsolUserPrincipalName -UserPrincipalName $UPN -NewUserPrincipalName $newUPN
```

but I can't seem to make it work via MS Graph.  The docs for graph imply that UPN can be updated like other attributes (c.v. http://graph.microsoft.io/en-us/docs/api-reference/v1.0/api/user_update, for example). I'm wondering though if because UPN is a key, maybe that makes update not work?  I also don't think this is a permission issue, those usually throw "Insufficient privileges to complete the operation." which is not what I'm seeing.

Thank you!

UPDATE1: Here's everything I can fish out of the Error object from a re-attempt this morning :

```
{
  "error": {
    "code": "Service_InternalServerError",
    "message": "Encountered an internal server error.",
    "innerError": {
      "request-id": "cbb08d3c-1143-4d0b-8722-5230b00bd00f",
      "date": "2016-02-15T16:48:15"
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are you able to make a UPN change between un-federated domains? How about for a user that is not synced form on-premises? (Trying to rule out the fact that the domain is federated, and that the user is mastered on-prem.)

Comment: @PhilippeSignoret: I can make a UPN change for a newly created user with an un-federated domain successfully via MS Graph.  The newly created user was cloud-only and not sync'd from on premise. I do not think I can create a synced-from-on-premise, non-federated UPN user as our AAD Sync Connect only syncs users with federated UPNs.  I did try changing directly from one federated domain to another, but got Request_BadRequest which was expected (rather than 500 Internal Server error).

Comment: @ChrisAlexander: Can you repro and update your question with more information please?  We need the client-request-id and a timestamp.  This will allow us to trace the issue further.  I'm not sure if this operation is possible, but even so it should not return a 500.

Comment: @DanKershaw-MSFT - I've updated the original request with a text dump of the entire error object include request-id and timestamp.  Apologies for the slight delay.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I took a look at the trace, and I will file a bug on our side for the 500 error (we can certainly do better here).  Based on the trace, if you are updating a user by renaming them out of a federated domain into a cloud managed domain, you MUST provide/set a password as part of the request (using passwordProfile complex type).  That is why the request is failing according to the logs.  Please let us know if this solves your issue.

Comment: That did the trick!  I had to slightly adjust my Azure app permissions to allow this app to submit a password.  I can also confirm that you do not have to submit a password when changing to a federated domain (as ultimately my app is changing the user from one federated domain to another, but must pass temporarily through the cloud-managed domain first).  Edit:  Thank you!!!

Comment: I was just able to modify the upn of a user from one federated domain to the other directly using the graph api. Has this behavior changed recently? I was also able to move from a federated to a managed domain, without including a new password.